# Issue to gradlew build SonarQube (org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException:)

Tags: android, android-studio, sonarqube

I am trying to integrate Sonar qube in android project so for that I done with build.gradle file change as per [guide line](https://medium.com/@vtuforum/integrate-sonarqube-for-android-application-development-8e40ec28e343). but when I run command :

```
gradlew sonarqube -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 —- info -stacktrace
```

Its give me Error :

```
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:sonarqube'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:60)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:128)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:46)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ExecuteTasks.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:311)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.runTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:202)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:132)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:107)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:78)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:152)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:100)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:75)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:71)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:45)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ScannerException: Unable to execute SonarQube
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory$1.run(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:84)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory$1.run(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:71)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:71)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:67)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doStart(EmbeddedScanner.java:218)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.start(EmbeddedScanner.java:156)
        at org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask.run(SonarQubeTask.java:98)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:141)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:731)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:705)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
        ... 101 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to bootstrap from server. Bootstrap index was:
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" charset="UTF-8"/><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><link re
l="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="/appl
e-touch-icon-60x60.png"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png"><l
ink rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png"><link rel="apple-tou
ch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="18
0x180" href="/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png"><link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico"><meta name="application-name" content="SonarQube"/><meta name="msapplication-Tile
Color" content="#FFFFFF"/><meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/mstile-512x512.png"/><link href="/css/sonar.b5628b8d.css" rel="stylesheet"><title>SonarQube</title></head><bo
dy><div id="content"><div class="global-loading"><i class="spinner global-loading-spinner"></i> <span class="global-loading-text">Loading...</span></div></div><script>window.baseUrl=
""</script><script src="/js/vendor.d9aca469.js"></script><script src="/js/app.b5628b8d.js"></script></body></html>
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.Jars.getScannerEngineFiles(Jars.java:88)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.Jars.download(Jars.java:70)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.JarDownloader.download(JarDownloader.java:39)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory$1.run(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:75)
        ... 120 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.Jars.getScannerEngineFiles(Jars.java:84)
        ... 123 more
```

**App Gradle ::**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: 'buildscripts/dependencies.gradle'
apply plugin: "org.sonarqube"
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'Ssdebug'
            keyPassword 'asd@123'
            storeFile file('E:/asd/MobileApp-Android/debug_keystore.jks')
            storePassword 'asd@123'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "id"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        buildConfigField 'boolean', 'DEMO_MODE', 'false'
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            testCoverageEnabled true
        }
        qa {
            applicationIdSuffix ".qa"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            debuggable true
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            testCoverageEnabled true
        }
    }
}
    buildscript {
        ext {
            springBootVersion = '1.5.4.RELEASE'
        }
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
            maven {
                url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
            }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
            classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.5"
        }
    }

sonarqube {
    properties {

            def libraries = project.android.sdkDirectory.getPath() + "/platforms/android-23/android.jar"
            property "sonar.sources", "src/main/java"
            property "sonar.binaries", "build/intermediates/classes/debug"
            property "sonar.libraries", libraries
            property "sonar.tests", "src/test/java, src/androidTest/java"
            property "sonar.java.test.binaries", "build/intermediates/class/debug"
            property "sonar.java.test.libraries", libraries
            property "sonar.jacoco.reportPath", "build/jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec"
            property "sonar.java.coveragePlugin", "jacoco"
            property "sonar.junit.reportsPath", "build/test-results/debug"
            property "sonar.android.lint.report", "build/outputs/lint-results"
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile supportDependencies.values() //All Support Libs
    compile utilities.values() //All utilities Libs

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    //All Support Libs
    //All utilities Libs
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    //    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile project(':module-componentkit-release')
    compile project(':module-foundation-release')
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.0'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.7.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.16'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.0.1'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile 'com.github.heetch:Android-country-picker:1.0.6'
    compile 'com.braintreepayments:card-form:3.1.1'
    compile 'io.card:android-sdk:5.5.0'
    implementation project(':FORTSDKv1.4.1')
    compile 'com.victor:lib:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'com.shamanland:fonticon:0.1.8'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    compile('com.nispok:snackbar:2.11.+') {
        // exclusion is not necessary, but generally a good idea.
        exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:20.0'
    compile 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk16:1.46'
    compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
    compile 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2@aar'
    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:2.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    compile 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.5.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.0.2'

}
```

***Project Gradle :***

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.6.1"

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://jitpack.io'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Please help me Friends for this..

Comment: Please check instructions provided here https://sonarqube4android.wordpress.com/2018/01/19/have-code-quality-review-on-your-android-project/

Comment: @Suresh, tried to change as per this tutorial but no luck.

Comment: The plugin version for app and project gradle are different. Could it be the problem ?

Comment: 1) was your server fully up when you tried to start analysis? 2) what do you get when you try to access the host URL you used? 3) what happens if you add a space between `:9000` and --info?

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam can I do same thing with git project? if yes can you give some example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I figure out Solution my self :**

added following stuff in gradle.properties

```
systemProp.sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000
systemProp.sonar.login=admin
systemProp.sonar.password=admin
```

**change in gradle :**

```
sonarqube {
    properties {

            def libraries = project.android.sdkDirectory.getPath() + "/platforms/android-23/android.jar"
        property "sonar.projectName", "MobileApp-Android"
        property "sonar.projectKey", "com.sar.saudirail"
        property "sonar.sourceEncoding", "UTF-8"
        property "sonar.sources", "src/main/java"
        property "sonar.exclusions", "build/**,**/*.png"
        property "sonar.tests", "src/test/java, src/androidTest/java"
        property "sonar.import_unknown_files", true
        property "sonar.android.lint.report", "./build/outputs/lint-results.xml"
    }
}
```

and apply command and its works. Thanks all of you for help.